# Multiple select from m2m field in Django

Tags: django

I have an Image model and a Tag model, these models are connected by an m2m relationship. How do I select an Image that has a given set of Tags.
For example.
Images tagged with Tag1 and Tag2 but not Tag3.

I tried to do it like this:

```
Image.objects.filter(Q(tags__tag='Tag1') & Q(tags__tag='Tag2') & ~Q(tags__tag='Tag3'))
```

But it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Image.objects.filter(Q(tags__tag='Tag1') | Q(tags__tag='Tag2')).exclude(tags__tag='Tag3')

Comment: I need select images not with Tag1 or Tag2, but with Tag1 and Tag2. Only images that have both tags.